# C# DateTime with a specific time offset

Tags: c#, datetime, xml-serialization

I am working with an API that expects a DateTime to be serialized with a specific timezone offset included in it (always -6 hours) but I can't figure out how to create it in this format. They specifically want it to serialize to this: 2014-07-22T00:00:00.000-06:00 (note the -06:00 on the end)

I have tried this which just gives me a normal date time:

```
TimeZoneInfo centralZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("CST No Daylight Savings",   TimeSpan.FromHours(-6), "CST No Daylight Savings", "CST No Daylight Savings");
this.lastHardBounceDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1), centralZone);
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Taken From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769(v=vs.110).aspx

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```

Comment: That still just serializes to <DateValue>2014-08-04T07:40:29.947458</DateValue> - they say it should come through with -06:00 at the end so: 2014-08-04T07:40:29.947458-06:00

Comment: Maybe you should consider changing the datatype to string and use some kind of datetime format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The problem is that they have provided me with a SOAP API that takes a DateTime object. So it appears that I am just stuck here.